# Smart Admin add child row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, smartadmin

[image]I'm working with the smart admin bootstrap template however I'm not able to figure out how to add child rows on a datatable whenever I want to add additional information for a particular record. Does anybody know how I can achieve this or whether Smart Admin have implemented such a functionality?

Attached is what I want to achieve:

Comment: please post some code example and explain better what you want to archive

Comment: @Maxwell Edited my post

Comment: You can post what you want to archive (illustration)? If i understand it, you can add another table on a table-cell.